# Latex newcommand underlined section

Tags: sectioning, underline

I have to write a proposal in LaTeX in which there are normal headlines defined by conventional LaTeX commands (`\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, and `\subsubsubsection`), but there are also other special headlines for the work packages. These headlines have to be underlined, shifted to left and italic.

Basically, it should look like this:

[image: How it should look like.]

Probably, it is a simple problem. This is what I tried:

```
\newcommand{\specsection}[1]{\noindent\textit{\underline{#1}}}
```

It has basically the problem that headlines run out of the page.

```
\newcommand\specsection[1]{\begin{flushleft}
\underline{\textit{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}}}
\end{flushleft}}
```

This one does not do the underlining correct.

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: One should never use `\underline` outside of math mode. For text-mode underlining, load the `ulem` package, preferably with the option `normalem`, and then write `\uline{…}`. That way, automatic line Breaking is not disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you change the definition of `\specsection` to

```
\newcommand\specsection[1]{%
     \par\noindent{\raggedright
     \emph{\uline{#1}}
     \par}}
```

This requires loading the `ulem` package -- preferably with the option `normalem`.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for this example
\newcommand\specsection[1]{%
     \par\noindent{\raggedright
     \emph{\uline{#1}}
     \par}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily % optional
Here you have normal text.
\specsection{Work package 1: One problem is that header lines sometimes become very long and you need two lines for them.}
Here you have normal text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Mico.

A simple solution is:

```
\newcommand{\specsection}[1]{\noindent\textit{\uline{#1}}}
```

Or

```
\newcommand{\specsection}[1]{\raggedright\noindent\textit{\uline{#1}}\linebreak\noindent}
```

Comment: Don't use `\linebreak` to terminate the current *paragraph".

Comment: @thinkdeep You will almost certainly want to start a new paragraph before setting you title as in Mico's answer, otherwise your title will sometimes be printed in the middle of a line.